# Best schema design for Journal app storing notes as array or just object?

Tags: mongodb, schema

I am building a Journal app for practice. Journal of a user contains many notes. Right now, I am creating a journal object for every user and storing notes as an array. Is this the right approach or should I just create a Note object for every note?
The reason I created an object for all notes is that most of the time app loads all notes, so I thought this will be a good approach but I am facing some difficulties now(for eg. implementing search in notes, I cannot search for notes using MongoDB Atlas Search cause it returns the entire object i.e Journal if it matches a query.)
Which is the right schema design for such an app? And where do I learn how to design schemas?
My current Schema design is:

```
  {
  userid: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  notes: [
    {
      content: {
        type: String,
      },
      Date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: you can try `Array.prototype.filter()` to filter the content you want

Comment: You can store notes as an array field as long as the array doesn't grow forever - the MongoDB document has size limit of 16 MB. See [Embedded Document Pattern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/#embedded-document-pattern).  In general, you can search notes array for a specific note or update existing notes using array operators. And, also, search and retrieve specific notes/fields using filtering or projection.